# DISTRO 'poky' not found. Please set a valid DISTRO in your local.conf

Tags: xilinx, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

New to Yocto. Trying to build an image for Xilinx Zynq. Followed instructions on https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-petalinux. Don't need everything there, so removed some of the layers. When I execute `bitbake zynq-generic` I get the following error:

```
$ bitbake petalinux-image
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

    DISTRO 'poky' not found. Please set a valid DISTRO in your local.conf


Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my `bblayers.conf`

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"


BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-xfce \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/openembedded-core/meta \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-qt5 \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/openembedded-core/meta-selftest \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/openembedded-core/meta-skeleton \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-xilinx \
    ${TOPDIR}/layers/meta-petalinux \
    "

MACHINE = "zynq-generic"

DISTRO ?= "poky"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The MACHINE and DISTRO variables should be in your local.conf.

Have a look at their local.conf [example](https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-petalinux/blob/master/conf/local.conf.sample).

Your DISTRO should be:

```
DISTRO ?= "petalinux"
```

You're not using [Poky](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/) because meta-petalinux draws directly from oe-core and bitbake:

```
...
This layer depends on:

URI: git://git.openembedded.org/bitbake
URI: git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
```

To learn more about Poky check out [this page](https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/poky).

Basically Poky combines parts of oe-core and bitbake. Xilinx's meta-petalinux instead pulls those things in separately.

Also, their setup instructions are probably missing this step:

```
TEMPLATECONF=meta-petalinux/conf source {path-to}/oe-init-build-env
```

This tells bitbake to use "meta-petalinux" local.conf.sample and bblayers.conf.sample. You'll notice that they include many layers in their [bblayers.conf.sample](https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-petalinux/blob/master/conf/bblayers.conf.sample) that you are not including.

Since you have already setup your local.conf and bblayers.conf, I would simply look at their examples and correct your files as needed. You may also want to look up the variable names that meta-petalinux changes in the [Bitbake Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) or [Yocto Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html). This will give you a better idea of what they did and why (if you care :) ).

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo there. `local.conf` should be replaced with `bblayers.conf`

Comment: No worries. You're not using poky, but rather oe-core. Your distro should be set to the line above in your local.conf file.

Comment: Now I'm confused even more. If this layer depends on `bitbake` and `openembedded-core`, then shouldn't they both be included to the `bblayers.conf`. Right now `bitbake` is not included.

Comment: Yes, I believe their setup instructions miss a step. See my answer for details.